# Whole RSS Feed from iso-8859-1 into UTF-8

Tags: php, rss, alexa-skills-kit

I'm working on an Amazon Echo Skill, which is based on an RSS feed.
This feed is encoded in iso-8859-1, but needs to be in UTF-8.

Because the skill only needs the `<encoded>` tag in my case, i tried:

```
$content = $xml->getElementsByTagName("encoded")
                ->item($i)->nodeValue;
utf8_encode($content);
```

But this didn't do anything. Also in the header when i load the file via:

```
$file = 'old.xml';
    $xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
    $xml->load($file);
```

It still says: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>`

Now i can't find a way for solving this problem. Maybe change the whole feed to UTF-8. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer found.
I loaded the feed with:

`$feed = file_get_contents(' .... ');`

and encoded it with:

```
$feed = utf8_encode($feed); 
$feed = str_replace('encoding="iso-8859-1"', 'encoding="utf-8"', $feed);
```

Now works fine for me.

Also i changed the load-function to:

```
$xml = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$xml->loadXML($feed);
```